# Determine if $f(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right)$ is n-times differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The function $f$ is defined as
$$f(x)=\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ \frac { 1 }{ t }  } \ln\left(\frac { 1 }{ 1-t }\right)\, dt$$

By using the second fundamental theorem of calculus, we get the first derivative:
$$f^{ (1) }( x ) ={ \frac { 1 }{ x } } \ln\left(\frac { 1 }{ 1-x } \right)$$

My question is: Is there a quick way to determine if $f(x)$ is $n$-times differentiable on $(-1,1)$ without taking any further derivatives but still somehow get the $n$th derivative term? I want to do a Taylor expansion around $x=0$.

Comment: $f^1$? Should be $f'$. More important is what's happening at $0,$ which needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Why does it matter this much? If i wanted to integrate it would matter but by taking the derivative i get a constant value $\frac { dF(0) }{ dx } $. Or do I miss understand something?

Comment: Why do you think $f'(0)$ exists?

Comment: OFC ur right. So what could I do? using the limit definition for an n-th term expression?

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes i did, but i dont understand the reasoning since i havn't studied MacClaurin series in class yet.

Comment: MacClaurin is just Taylor based at $0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the series
$$
\log\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k}
$$
Thus, the function in question is a [Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k^2}
$$
which is infinitely differentiable on $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand seems to have a problem at $0,$ but it really  doesn't. In fact the integrand is analytic and equals its MacClaurin series in all of $(-1,1).$ Therefore its integral has the same property. And analytic functions are infinitely differentiable.

Some details: For $t\in (-1,1) \setminus \{0\},$ we have

$$\ln \left(\frac{1}{1-t}\right) = -\ln (1-t) = t +t^2/2+t^3/3 + \cdots.$$

Thus the integrand equals $1+t/2+t^2/3 + \cdots$ in $(-1,1) \setminus \{0\}.$

Answer (score 1):

You might have problems at
$0$ and $1$.
Other than that,
you can apply

$(fg)^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}
$

and find
$(\frac1{x})^{(k)}$
and
$(-\log(1-x))^{(k)}
$.

Comment: good approach! i did it for (1/x) but it really takes a long time finding a recursive formula (this would screw me in exams)

Comment: There's no trouble at $1$ since the domain is $(-1,1).$

Comment: Since $\log'(x) = 1/x$, the successive derivatoves are not a problem.